# ol-ext: map control bar is not show on the map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

In my app have a problem with the ol-ext: map control bar. It doesn't show on the map and I don't understand why. This is my code:

```js
// Main control bar
var mainbar = new ol.control.Bar();

/* Standard Controls */
mainbar.addControl (new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({  extent: [ 265971,6243397 , 273148,6250665 ] }));
mainbar.addControl (new ol.control.Rotate());
mainbar.addControl (new ol.control.FullScreen());
//mainbar.setPosition('bottom-right');

this.map.addControl(mainbar);
```

I also added on my load.js file *addScriptFile('//viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.js');*

If I change the last line like that:  *this.map.addControl(this.mainbar);* I have this list of errors:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMap' of undefined
    at ol.Map.<anonymous> (ol-debug.js:17839)
    at ol.Collection.boundListener (ol-debug.js:7277)
    at ol.Collection.ol.events.EventTarget.dispatchEvent (ol-debug.js:7697)
    at ol.Collection.insertAt (ol-debug.js:8341)
    at ol.Collection.push (ol-debug.js:8368)
    at ol.Map.ol.PluggableMap.addControl (ol-debug.js:17908)
    at constructor.initMap (Map.js:219)
    at constructor.afterrender (BaseMap.js:275)
    at constructor.fire (ext-all-debug.js:20731)
    at constructor.doFireEvent (ext-all-debug.js:21700)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, and actually it was really stupid, I am sorry.
I left the last line as *this.map.addControl(mainbar);* and I had to add in my load.js file also the line:

addStyleFile('//viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.css');

so now it look like that:

```js
addStyleFile('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/' + olVersion + '/ol.css');
    if (debugMode) {
        addScriptFile('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/' + olVersion + '/ol-debug.js');
        addScriptFile('//viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.js');
        addStyleFile('//viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.css');
    } else {
        addScriptFile('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/' + olVersion + '/ol.js');
        addScriptFile('//viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.js');
        addStyleFile('//viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.css');
    }
```